# Почему в /dev нет сетевых устройств?

Tags: linux, c, сеть

у меня появился, может быть, для кого-то странный вопрос. Почему в Linux, в devfs нет сетевых устройств (сетевых интерфейсов)? Они же по логике вещей все равно устройства, хоть и тип их сетевой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Они же по логике вещей все равно устройства

Нет. С точки зрения NIX* систем, утсройство - это файл. И как для любого другого файла, по отношению к нему должна быть возможность выполнить 5 операций:

1. Открытие файла
2. Запись в файл
3. Чтение из файла
4. IOCTL
5. Закрытие файла.

Драйвер **физической** сетевой карточки этим требованиям не удовлетворяет никак. Зато они отлично подходят для **логического**  понятия "сокет".

Вот сокеты можно открывать, закрывать, писать в них, читать из них и управлять ими. Поэтому, идеология работы с сетевыми сокетами почти дословно копирует идеологию работы с файлами.

Но "железка" сетевой карточки в эту стройную картину не укладывается!

Comment: Где вы этого набрались?

Comment: @0andriy  Вот здесь: "Драйверы устройств Linux", гл. 17  "Сетевые драйверы", 

Есть несколько важных различий между смонтированными дисками и интерфейсами доставки пакетов. Сетевой интерфейс не имеет такой точки входа в каталоге /dev. Нормальные операции с файлами (чтение, запись и так далее) не имеют смысла применительно к сетевым интерфейсам, так что невозможно применять к ним подход Unix "всё есть файл". Таким образом, сетевые интерфейсы существуют в их собственном пространстве имён и экспортируют другой набор операций.

Comment: "не имеют смысла" - почему? потому что подключенны к стеку сети, а сетевой стек исключительно сам читает и пишет.  Но это все оптимизации эзернет. Для других протоколов это тоже справедливо?

Answer (score 4):

Не соглашусь с Sergey.

Драйвер сетевой может прекрасно вписаться в файл. Примеры этому tun, macvtap сходу. Тут дело в том, что сетевой управляет одна подпрограмма - сетевой стек ОС и совместное использование невозможно. Нет смысла создавать файл, которым нельзя пользоваться. Файл создается для использования устройств именно из Userspace.

Также при использовании USB устройств напрямую, через libusb, файл устройства из dev пропадает.

ПС.

macvtap (используется в 99,9999999% случаев в виртуалках) добавляет ещё один мак адрес на физическую сетевую карту и символьное устройство в dev. Если сформировать вручную L2 пакет и записать его в /dev/tap5, то он выйдет из сетевушки, если читать это файл, то там будут прилетать пакеты адресованные назначенному MAC адресу.

```
modprobe macvtap
ip link add link enp5s0  name macvtap0 type macvtap
ls -la /dev/tap*
```

crw------- 1 root root 235, 1 окт 16 13:24 /dev/tap5

ППС. Linux это не UNIX. Нет необходимости отображать все устройства как файлы.

Comment: Уточните, что такое *mactap*. А то даже Гугла всеведующий этого не знает :-(

Comment: @Sergey macvtap, опечатался чуток

Comment: "все устройства как файлы". **Витруальная** сетевая карточка это **не**  устойство. Точно так же, как **виртуальная** машина - это не машина.

Comment: А чем виртуальная отличается от реальной со стороны взаимодействия пользователя?

Comment: "со стороны взаимодействия пользователя?"

- А причём тут взаимодействие с пользователем? У Вас есть автомобиль? Если есть, то может у Вас есть и гаражный бокс. Предположим, что ГСК называентся "/dev". И у Вас там бокс под название "sda". Вечером, возвращаясь с работы, вы вспомнили, что играя в "Cars Simulator" Вы завели там себе новый авто и назвали его "sdb". И поэтому вы идёте к админитратору ГСК и говорите, что хотите арендавать бокс для виртуального авто.  Он же ничем не "отличается от реального со стороны взаимодействия пользователя"

Comment: файлы нужны ТОЛЬКО для взаимодействия с пользователем! И не надо глупых аналогий. Виртуальный автомобиль не перевозит полезный груз, а вот виртуальная сетевая передает полезную нагрузку в реальную среду.

Comment: "И не надо глупых аналогий." - Вы правы! :-)